# Plotting the Degree Distribution in Python iGraph

Tags: python, plot, igraph, cairo

I want to plot the histogram of a degree distribution, but using the iGraph's plot() on the degree_distribution gives just that...a plot, but with no title, no labels, no nothing, like this:
[image]

How can I add annotations to this plot?

Comment: Any reasons you are not using a dedicated plotting library like matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

Igraph is not meant to be a fully functional plotting library - the plot that it can generate for degree distributions is meant only for quock "eyeballing". Use a dedicated plotting library like matplotlib. The `bins()` method of the degree distribution object may be used to extract the bin counts of the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

```
import igraph as ig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate a 100-nodes random graph
g = ig.Graph.Barabasi(100, 2)

bins = 20
plt.hist(g.degree(), bins)
plt.show()
```

[image]